# How to delete files that have part of the name listed in a .txt file

Tags: powershell, txt

I have a folder on an external SSD that contains 2000+ files  and a .txt file in the same folder that contains specific pieces of title; for example: the files are named "file_title-file_id.json" and in the .txt file I have slightly less than 2000 of those "file_id".
I need to delete all the files in that folder that contain in the title those "file_id" listed in the .txt file

I have basically no experience with scripts and all the "solutions" found searching the web don't seem to work for me
things like:

```
gc .\MyListOfFilesIWantToDelete.txt | %{gci $_ -Recurse | Remove-Item -WhatIf}
```

```
$TargetFolder = “Pathofyourfolder”
$Files = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Recurse| Where Name -in (gc List.txt) 
foreach ($File in $Files)
{ 
    write-host “Deleting File $File” -foregroundcolor “Red”;
    Remove-Item $File | out-null
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

EDIT:
working with the suggested code below, i ended with something that worked as intended only with those id's included in the .txt file

````
$folder_path = "D:\ambra"    # Replace with the path to your folder
$file_path = ".\list.txt"  # Replace with the path to your .txt file

# Read the file IDs from the .txt file and store them in an array
$file_IDs = Get-Content -Path $file_path

# Initialize a counter for the deleted files
$deleted_count = 0

# Get all files in the folder
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder_path -File

# Iterate through the files and delete those that match the file IDs
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $file_title, $file_id, $file_extension = $file.BaseName -split '-', 3
    if ($file_id -in $file_IDs) {
        # Increment the counter
        $deleted_count++
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Matched file_id: $file_id"
        Remove-Item -Path $file.FullName -Force
    }
}
# Display the total count of deleted files
Write-Host "Total Deleted Files: $deleted_count"```

Thank you all for the help
````

Comment: How many strings are there?  It's pretty easy in cmd to do `del *file_id*`.

Comment: 1933 different id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward if you're looking to remove files based on certain criteria, such as the content in your .txt file.

```bash
# Define paths
$folder_path = "D:\path\to\your\folder"    # Replace with the path to your folder
$file_path = ".\MyListOfFilesIWantToDelete.txt"  # Replace with the path to your .txt file

# Create a HashSet
$file_IDs = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new()

# Read file IDs from the .txt file and populate our HashSet
Get-Content -Path $file_path | ForEach-Object { $null = $file_IDs.Add($_) }

# Get all JSON files in the folder and filter by name
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder_path -Filter "*.json" -File | Where-Object -FilterScript {
        $file_ID = ($_.BaseName -split '-',2)[1]  # Extracting the file_id from the file name format "file_title-file_id"
        $file_IDs.Contains($file_ID)
} | Remove-Item -WhatIf #Remove the files found
```

Save the file content to a `HashSet` for faster lookup, then filter with `Where-Object` by splitting the file name in 2 strings at the `-`, then selecting the 2nd string (your *file ID*) to compare to what's in the `HashSet`.

---

*Remove the `-WhatIf` safety parameter when you've dictated those are the results you're after.*

Comment: at first it didn't run, but looking there was a "(" missing here "$file_ID = $_.BaseName -split '-',2)[1]"
added it and it runs, but executing it shows that Remove-Item is applied on every file in the folder instead of only on those containing the .txt specified id in the title

Comment: i modified my initial question to include the solution i come up with; thank you for your help